# Graphql.schema types and inputs to python classes

Tags: python, graphql, aws-appsync

I am currently working on a GraphQL API using aws-appsync and lambda-resolvers written in python. Inside my lambdas, I am working with dicts only. With a growing project size, it becomes hard to follow the logic without knowledge of the graphql.schema. Therefore, I would like to use the corresponding python class representations of my GraphQL types/inputs.

I am looking for a simple library which transforms the types and inputs from my graphql.schema to python classes, optimally leveraging something like pydantic.

On the web, I only found full client/server libraries like for example Strawberry and Ariadne.

Does a library exist that satisfies my needs, or do I need to implement it on my own?

Answer (score 1):

We can using [datamodel-code-generator](https://koxudaxi.github.io/datamodel-code-generator/graphql/) for your problem. The code generator can create pydantic models from GraphQL schema definitions.

Or we can using my old project https://pypi.org/project/graphql2python/ for this (i recommended using datamodel-code-generator).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it can help but I just published a kind of python-graphql mapper transforming graphql responses in Python objects (having declared the python class and it's fields) and vice versa.

https://github.com/dapalex/py-graphql-mapper

So far it manages only basic query and response, if it will become useful I will keep implementing more features.

Try to have a look and see if it can help you